# How to escape wildcard characters in Microsoft Log Parser query?

Tags: escaping, logparser

How to provide an escape character in the logparser `LIKE` condition?

Current query:

```
SELECT EXTRACT_TOKEN(cs-uri-stem,1,'/') AS AppPath, Count(*) AS ReqCount
FROM <MyLogFile> 
WHERE AppPath LIKE '%_%'
```

Example data:

```
+-------------+
| cs-uri-stem |
+-------------+
| 120_ABC     |
| 321_XYZ     |
| 11_BXY      |
| ALPHA       |
| BETA        |
+-------------+
```

From the above data, I would like to filter only the rows that contains an underscore.

I tried the usual escape options in SQL like `angle brackets [_]`, `LIKE '%_%' ESCAPE '\' clause`, but they do not help.

Comment: The documentation suggests to use the unicode notation `LIKE '%\u005F%'` (cannot verify myself right now so I did not put it in an answer)

Comment: @Filburt Sorry, did not work

Comment: Revisiting the help file I found: *" ... LIKE 'ab\_d': matches the "ab_d" string (e.g. "ab_d", "AB_d") ..."* so in your case `LIKE '%\\_%' should work.

Comment: @Filburt Perfect! Please add your comment as answer for me to mark it so. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Logparser help file:

> Wildcard pattern matching characters can be used as literal characters. To use a wildcard character as a literal character, escape the wildcard character with the '\' (backslash) character.
>  
>   Examples: 
>   LIKE 'ab_d': matches the "ab_d" string (e.g. "ab_d", "AB_d")
>   LIKE 'a\%c%': matches all the strings that start with "a%c" (e.g. "a%cdefg", "A%c")

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT EXTRACT_TOKEN(cs-uri-stem,1,'/') AS AppPath, Count(*) AS ReqCount
FROM <MyLogFile> 
WHERE AppPath LIKE '%\_%'
```